# Can't run "X -configure", "Server is already active" error

Tags: xorg

in order to fix a problem with the setup of the screen brightness I try to create a xorg.conf

This is done by the command X -configure right?

Trying to run this command as root, I will get:

```
Fatal server error:
Server is already active for display 0
    If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X0-lock
    and start again.
```

Trying to run this command in recovery modus, I will get the same. After remove the mentioned file I get the error: cannot create file /tmp/.X0-lock 
Just to make sure: Yep I have the rights as I am logged in as root.

Comment: I`m with the same problem and after do this in the 3. sudo Xorg -configure show List of video driver
...
...
...
(++) Using config file? "/root/xorg.conf.new"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices.
Configuration filed.
Server terminated with error (2). Closing log file. Please help me!!!!!

Answer (score 7):

I think you shall have to stop the xserver first.
Try this:

1. Open a Terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and login
2. `sudo stop lightdm` (or kdm or gdm instead of lightdm if you installed kubuntu or GNOME shell)
3. `sudo Xorg -configure`
4. `sudo start lightdm` (or kdm or gdm instead of lightdm if you installed kubuntu or GNOME shell)

Answer (score 3):

run `ps auxw |grep X`

and kill the process

then run again.

refer:http://git.net/ml/apple.fink.beginners/2002-08/msg00246.html