# fatal error when launching startx: server is already active

Tags: 12.04, xserver

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04. Earlier today I launched `startx` and got a blank wallpaper-like screen with nothing on there. I thought maybe it was taking time to load but it would just remain stuck there. Looking for a way to get back to the command prompt, I pressed `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F6` and got back to the command prompt. Later today, I tried launching `startx` again and got this error:

```
Fatal server error:
Server is already active for display 0
    If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X0-lock
    and start again.

Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
    at http://wiki.x.org
for help.

ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyInvalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyxinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Resource temporarily unavailable
xinit: server error
```

Someone [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69896/cant-run-x-configure-server-is-already-active-error) suggested to type in `sudo stop lightdm` and someone else over [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320666/how-do-i-kill-the-x-server) suggests to type `sudo service lightdm stop`, however both give me the following message:

```
stop: Unknown instance:
```

I tried `killall X` which gives me:

```
X: no process found
```

I'm not so sure about deleting `/tmp/.X0-lock` because the first link up there says that deleting it just gives you the error message `cannot create file /tmp/.X0-lock` instead. By the way `cat /tmp/.X0-lock` gives me:

```
    14275
```

but that process doesn't seem to show up in `top`, although it may be way at the bottom, I'm not sure how to scroll down.

What should I try next?